# How does height:auto interact with line-height:0 and different font-size

Tags: css, font-size

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>Some text here...</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

The `div` gets `height: 0` in this circumstance.

---

However, when I specify a larger `font-size` like

```css
span {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Although there's `line-height: 0`, the `div` gets a non-zero height.

<s>You can check the demo at https://jsfiddle.net/cjvpLfv2/</s>

EDIT: add one more demo at https://jsfiddle.net/cjvpLfv2/12/

If I apply `font-size: 100px` to both `span` and `div`, the `div` gets `height: 0px` again

---

My question is how does `height: auto` interact with `line-height` and `font-size` in this simple situation (a block-level container with only one inline element)

Comment: This has nothing to do with height: auto, and everything to do with line-height: 0.

Comment: @BoltClock, `line-height: 0` means a minimum line height of 0. I think it is more related to how `height: auto` is calculated.

Comment: And height: auto means the height of the content, so the used line height is, evidently, non-zero, and that is what's giving the BCB its height. There really is nothing more to height: auto than what it is.

Comment: @BoltClock, What does BCB mean? I have tried adjusting line-height and it seems that the line-height is assigned 0px and is effective. There might be some other factor that dictates the div's height. I added another interesting demo in my edit. Please check it out.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late, but your question intrigued me so I decided to play around with it. After some time, I discovered the answer is actually pretty simple:

**The height of div is equal to the line-height.**

The reason why your line-height becomes non-0 is because you have different font-sizes. It doesn't matter that this size difference is between div and span, you could have 2 different font-sizes within the span element. The point is that as soon as you have 2 different font-sizes the line-height becomes non-0.

I don't know the exact formula, but it seems based upon the difference in size, more specifically the difference in distance between the middle of both sizes. You'll see that the bottom and top border of div will align with the middle of the smallest and largest font-size respectively.

You can easily demonstrate this by adding AaGg between the opening div and span tag of your second block of html code, as such:

```
<div>AaGg
<span class=big-font-size>AaGg</span>AaGg
</div>
```

I don't know why or the exact details of computation, but this newly calculated line-height basically overrides your specified line-height: 0;

Answer (score 0):

**1) Font-size dictates the line-height.**
If nothing is defined, [the normal factor for line-height seems to be 1.2](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values).

**2) Line height dictates automatic box height**, irrespective of font size. (In many cases, people don't define line height, thus essentially “font-size plus a fudge factor” determine box height, which appears natural). **Update:** Of course, that's what's type inside demands. Demands of boxes come on top. (And, inline or not, space is a box...). Frank-ly, I still miss a piece of the puzzle.

**3) If you use font-size 0 and line height 100, I do get a zero-height box:**

```
<div style='font-size:100px; line-height: 0'>
  <span>Some</span>
</div>
```

[see codepen here (last box has your use case)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKLwmN). Box 4 to 6 proves point (2).

The line-height you get has to do with giving part of the styling to the inner `<span>`, not the `<div>`. [See here.](https://jsfiddle.net/cjvpLfv2/3/)

Comment: Your point (3) has typo. Can you provide more detail on what is the "fudge factor" that dictates box height?

Comment: By (seemingly) fudge factor I mean the font-size “plus 20%” (the 1.2 mentioned in (1)). Is this answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `line-height` CSS style is 0 on all elements, including the `span` elements, it appears to be displayed differently in the browser. I've tried to add multiple lines to the spans, and the height of the outer `div` multiplies accordingly:

https://jsfiddle.net/cjvpLfv2/4/

So it seems that the browser does not allow a line-height of 0 for large font-sizes. The font-size where line-height goes above 0 appears to be 17px in Chrome.

If you set the spans' display property to `inline-block`, the lines no longer stack, but the line-height remains:

https://jsfiddle.net/cjvpLfv2/6/

If you set the spans' display property to `block`, line-height: 0 is applied as expected:

https://jsfiddle.net/cjvpLfv2/7/

I haven't found any documentation for this behavior, and the [box-model page on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) just claims that:

> for non-replaced inline elements, the amount of space taken up (the
>   contribution to the height of the line) is determined by the
>   line-height property